# Iphone 4S 8.1.1 Battery Problem

Tags: iphone, battery, ios

What else can I do to make my iPhone 4S work for as long as possible?

I have done all the "standard" battery saving techniques recommended on most sites, like:

- turn off background app refresh, automatic updates
- lower brightness all the way / disable auto brightness
- keep bluetooth and cellular Off always. Rarely use WiFi.
- No dynamic backgrounds.

The battery is still dying way too quickly.
My Battery Usage indicates that the Home and Lock Screen are using 30% of the battery. How is that possible? What is it doing??

Comment: Are you using any Notification Screen extensions? Location services?

Comment: Since you have ios 8 did you try to look at battery report? or is that not working on 4s?

Comment: I have most notifications off and Location Services is Completely off. By battery report do you mean Battery Usage?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Max life is 12 hours and very very little use.  It goes down by 5% per hour!!!

Apple said battery fine and I should only expect 10 to 12 hrs.  Back several iOS ago I could get well over 24 hours.

Sounds like the want to force us to get new iPhones 6.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the time of your iphone, I mean if its a 2010 factory made iphone the reason its obvious, otherwise you have to go to an Apple Service Retail/Shop and ask for a revision cause thats not normal.

Comment: What do you mean by a Revision? The product has passed the one year warranty point.

Answer (score 0):

I think iOS 8 will be the last ios the iphone 4s will support.

Apple said that there will be more software updates before that should add better preformance and new functions to the system.

The beta of iOS 8.2 made sure that the preformance on the iPhone 4s get a bit better.

When your iphone is a couple of years old, you can consider buying a new iphone or replace the battery (unofficially will be cheaper).

In the netherlands you can send in an iphone for a "whole unit replacement" but that is most of the times much more expansive than replacing a battery.

Answer (score 0):

> My Battery Usage indicates that the Home and Lock Screen are using 30%
>   of the battery

check how quickly it's set to autolock.  shorten it to one minute for a week and see if that changes anything.  if it's sitting at lock screen for a long time, it might as well just be dimmed and locked.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good advice here about reducing power usage and checking what's currently using it, but nobody has suggested replacing the battery. They just don't have as much capacity now as when they were manufactured. It isn't too difficult to do with the right tools, though if you aren't comfortable with the risk of breaking the phone you can pay someone to do it. [The parts and basic tools are about $30 including shipping.](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/iPhone/iPhone-4S-Replacement-Battery/IF115-005-2) I've heard $50 to $90 to have a shop replace it.

Answer (score -1):

Please check [this ultimate guide](http://www.scottyloveless.com/blog/2014/the-ultimate-guide-to-solving-ios-battery-drain) in regards to battery problems out.

Also I think you should take a look into:

- Settings > Location settings (which apps are allowed to use it and when)
- Settings > E-mail > Check your e-mail fetch/push settings.
- Settings > Notification center (which apps are allowed to push notifications e.g. messages, badges, sounds..)

It could also be a rogue app which is constantly using battery (it can be possible that you don't see that in settings > battery usage). I had that when i went from iOS6 > iOS7 and my battery only lasted for a 12/13hours. It was a rogue app that i had on my phone and did have a bug/problem with iOS7. It could be that it's one of your older apps which doesn't support yet iOS8 (it could work but maybe not as it should).

I'm also also using a iPhone 4S but with iOS 71.2. and don't have a battery drain. I can use it for about 24 hours without charging and 90% of the time it has WIFI access (but no 3G). I fetch my e-mail once an hour. No background processes allowed. Only a limited selection of apps that are allowed to show push notifications.

Comment: My iPhone 4s was fine under iOS 7 but the battery got worse as the OP says under IOS 8 which your answer does not deal with